# How to Convert javaScript json object into C# object in ajax success method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, razor-pages

I have this method on success of ajax call .

```
var SuccessMethodToGetNavigation = function (response) {

    recieveTopLevelAndSecondLevel(response);

};
```

Response I get from API is an object of NavigationViewModel in success method in the form of json. I want to cast this json object in C# NavigationViewModel class again to bind it with partial view model to get data in success method  and then pass it to partialView model that is bound with NavigationViewModel and want to perform other operations.

Is it possible to do this without using another ajax call to controller ?

Comment: add your ajax call snippet here.

Answer (score 0):

A way to use JSON in C# is with JSON.NET
Quick Starts & API [Documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) from JSON.NET - Official site help you work with it. 
An example of how to use it:

```
public class User
{
    public User(string json)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jUser = jObject["user"];
        name = (string) jUser["name"];
        teamname = (string) jUser["teamname"];
        email = (string) jUser["email"];
        players = jUser["players"].ToArray();
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string teamname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Array players { get; set; }
}

// Use
private void Run()
{
    string json = @"{""user"":{""name"":""asdf"",""teamname"":""b"",""email"":""c"",""players"":[""1"",""2""]}}";
    User user = new User(json);

    Console.WriteLine("Name : " + user.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Teamname : " + user.teamname);
    Console.WriteLine("Email : " + user.email);
    Console.WriteLine("Players:");

    foreach (var player in user.players)
        Console.WriteLine(player);
 }
```

Comment: here we are calling controller action to convert json object to c#. we make an additional call of ajax. why can't we do this in success method?

Comment: look this is my javaScript method.
var SuccessMethodToGetNavigation = function (response) {

    recieveTopLevelAndSecondLevel(response);

};

I want to do like this 
@Model = response;
Is It possible?

Comment: I told you to add your ajax call method here, so it will be cleared that what you actually trying to do

Comment: No you cannot access any of the ASP object via JS but there will be another way, you can store that response in cookies and can retrieve that on server

Comment: but i don't want to make 2 ajax calls to server first to API controller to get json data and then pass that json data  that we recieve in fist call into 2nd ajax call to MVC controller to convert it in C# object and pass to partial view.
I don't think that would be better approach.

Comment: Approaches will vary according to the situations but it seems there can be more solutions to your problem.

Comment: You can store that response in localstorage in the browser and can retrieve it without the second call for the PartialView

Comment: what i am doing . i am rendring response object into html using success method . because it's not passing to model so i can't directlly call to model.Property so i am doing this first in JS function then render it on dom